Triggering callback on derivedStateOf change
I want to trigger a callback once a derivedStateOf changes. My code currently looks like this:
var previouslySelectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }

val nowSelectedIndex by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        // some logic here
    }
}

nowSelectedIndex?.let { nowSelected ->
    if(previouslySelectedIndex == null || previouslySelectedIndex != nowSelected) {
        previouslySelectedIndex = nowSelected
        onSelectedItemChanged(nowSelected)
    }
}

That feels very verbose to me, especially considering that we know the derivedStateOf only triggers when it's changed. Is there really nothing like the following?
nowSelectedIndex.onChange { onSelectedItemChanged(nowSelected) }


You might want to check out LaunchedEffect. The block is triggered when the value of key changes.
LaunchedEffect(nowSelectedIndex) {
    onSelectedItemChanged(nowSelected)
}

There are many other useful composables besides LaunchedEffect, so I recommend checking out this documentation.

but isn't LaunchedEffect asynchronous and therefore it might be executed later than my original code?

@me.at.coding I don't think something is asynchronous means it will be run late. Also, recomposition is optimistic, so composable may not contain any side-effects which does not use Effect APIs.

hmm, my original implementation would have an invalid side effect with calling the callback without LaunchedEffect, correct?

@me.at.coding I would say it is unpredictable.
